# How to include field names when printing a Racket struct

Tags: struct, racket

Suppose I have this Racket code:

```
(struct pos (x y))
(displayln (pos 5 6))
```

This displays `#<pos>`. Is there a way to make it display the field names and values too?

With the `#:transparent` option, the values are displayed:

```
(struct pos (x y) #:transparent)
(displayln (pos 5 6))
```

This displays `#(struct:pos 5 6)`, but I also want to display the field names (`x` and `y`). Is there a way to display both the field names and values? For example: `#(struct:pos #:x 5 #:y 6)`.

I am looking for something similar to how Common Lisp structs are displayed. Common Lisp example:

```
(defstruct pos x y)
(format t "~A~%" (make-pos :x 5 :y 6))
```

This prints `#S(POS :X 5 :Y 6)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use third-party libraries, take a look at the very last example of [make-constructor-style-printer](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/structutils.html?q=constructor-style#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fstruct..rkt%29._make-constructor-style-printer%29%29).

If you don't mind using third-party libraries, you can just use Rebellion's [record](https://docs.racket-lang.org/rebellion/Records.html).